# vb access database password

Tags: security, ms-access, vba, vb6, connection-string

how can one create a password on a visual basic access database when you have a vb datagrid

Answer (score 2):

First, create a username and password for your MSAccess database (tools> security> set database password)
Next, make the [connectionstring](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access) with the resulting password.

Then go about your biz, connecting as usual.

Answer (score 0):

In your Microsoft Access database. Go to

> tools>security>set database password

Next make the connectionstring with the password you just entered.
It will connect if you did it correcly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, set a password column inside your table. Then, if the username and password match, the user should be entering the system. Otherwise, display an error message. Just don't forget to call the table from your `datagridview` to access interface.